# Rails: How do I solve the OCIError: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle

I have a model named "Carrier." In my controller, when I do a `Carrier.create(data)`, I get this error:

```
OCIError: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist: select carriers_seq.nextval id from dual
```

This is my code in my controller:

```
class CarriersController < ActionController::Base
    def index
        #stuff
    end

    def update
        @params["carriers"].each do |id, data|
            #data["id"]
            if Carrier.exists?(data["id"])
                carrier = Carrier.find(data["id"])
                carrier.update_attributes(data)
            else
                Carrier.create(data)
            end
        end
        redirect_to( :action => "index" )
    end
end
```

I've done some googling, and I found these two webpages about a solution:

http://niranjansarade.blogspot.com/2011/03/avoid-oracle-sequence-during.html

http://www.dixis.com/?p=127

Where should I be putting the code for the ActiveRecord? Should it be going in my model?

Is there another solution to my error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about ruby but it surely has been configured or programmed to use the database sequence carriers_seq. (A sequence is sort of a number generator)

How about creating this sequence in the database? try to execute the following statement in Oracle SQL*Plus:

```
create sequence CARRIERS_SEQ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also specify which sequence should be used by `self.sequence_name` command.

**Example:**

```
CarriersController < ActionController::Base
  self.sequence_name = 'seq_id'
end
```

Comment: How can I disable the sequence, I don't want use the sequence to generate my primary key. I want to manage it by myself.